# What is redundancy for databases?

Tags: database, mongodb

Im using mLab and got the message "Sandbox databases do not have redundancy and therefore are not suitable for production" while using the free tier Sandbox.

Comment: Same meaning as everywhere else. If your database server becomes unavailable/inaccessible for whatever reason, there won't be a spare one to pick up the workload.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you do not have any protection against service unavailability and data loss because there are no replicas. You should generally use a 3 or 5 node replica set in production to protect against both things when a failure occurs.

P.S. I'm curious why you're using mLab rather than [MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/atlas-free-tier-setup/)?

Comment: I dont know, never tryed MongoDB Atlas actually, In mLab i can set easly a sandbox in like 3 setps, is it that easy in Atlas?